# Is there a term for a class that is only intended to combine multiple classes?

Tags: python, class

Is it fair to define a class that inherits from multiple classes only for the sake of combining methods/attributes of all those classes?

Is there a specific term for such a class?

Example,

```
class Feature1( object ):
   def __init__( self, initTuple ):
      self.attr1 = initTuple.f1Attr1
      self.attr2 = initTuple.f1Attr2

   def f1Foobar( self ):
       print "Some operation here"


class Feature2( object ):
   def __init__( self, initTuple ):
      self.attr1 = initTuple.f2Attr1
      self.attr2 = initTuple.f2Attr2

   def f2Foobar( self ):
       print "Some operation here"


class Feature3( object ):
   def __init__( self, initTuple ):
      self.attr1 = initTuple.f3Attr1
      self.attr2 = initTuple.f3Attr2

   def f3Foobar( self ):
       print "Some operation here"


class CombiningClass( Feature3, Feature2, Feature1
   def __init__( self, initTuple ):
      Feature1.__init__( initTuple )
      Feature2.__init__( initTuple )
      Feature3.__init__( initTuple )
```

In this example, the only purpose of CombiningClass is to combine the features of the classes Feature1, Feature2 and Feature3

PS - This isn't my use-case. I have just tried to put it in simpler words

Comment: This is not the right way to use inheritance. You should be using composition.

Comment: Instead of having `Chair` subclass from the 3, it should have 3 objects that are instances of `Cushion`, `Wheels`, `Frame`. This would make it "*a Chair has a Cushion, has Wheels, and has a Frame*". Your sample means "*a Chair is a Cushion, and also a Wheel, and also a Frame*".

Comment: @GinoMempin I agree with your point and I see where you are coming from.
This is a mistake on my part that I used a wrong analogy.
I am just trying to understand if such classes are termed something specific in python

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no specific name for this, usually because the result is the "useful" concrete class, or some sort of aggregate of a base class and a few mixins.

This pattern can be seen in e.g. Werkzeug where Request and Response are the composition of a base class and a bunch of userful built-in mixins. This provides most users with a convenient ready-made object, but lets those who need specific sub-features or only want a subset of the base mixins get that by creating their own inheritance trees.